# Ruby delete folders older than X hours

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to delete the folders (recursively) if they are older than 4 hours.

Target folders looks like below

```
                               Date modified
    14_Nov_2017_05_05_PM       11/14/2017 04:06 PM
    14_Nov_2017_06_05_PM       11/14/2017 04:06 PM
    14_Nov_2017_06_15_PM       11/14/2017 05:06 PM
    .....
    27_Nov_2017_04_15_PM       11/27/2017 05:06 PM
    27_Nov_2017_05_15_PM       11/27/2017 08:06 AM
   and so on
```

I tried:

```
require 'fileutils'

directory = "E:\\My_work\\target\\check_dir"
Dir.chdir(directory)
Dir.glob("*").select{|f| File.mtime(f) < (Time.now - (60*60*4)) }.each{|f| FileUtils.rm(f) }
```

Script executes without throwing any error but the expected folders and its contents are not deleted.

Any help please, thanks.

Comment: But what are the actual mtimes for the folders?

Comment: Also, `FileUtils.rm` does not delete directories (which is reflected in its documentation)

Comment: Have you just made up the mtimes? They don't match the filenames. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @SergioTulentsev : I have edited my question. There are folders older more than 10 days but still its not getting deleted, thanks.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev : Sorry , currently I cannot access that VM so have given the arbitrary  data.

Comment: Well, that's not very useful :) Also, read my other comment.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev : I'm very new to Ruby, it would be really helpful if you could give me an alternate option/solution, many thanks.

Comment: Being new doesn't excuse you from reading documentation. Here's a hint: there is another, more fitting method in FileUtils.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159910/discussion-between-goku-and-sergio-tulentsev).